# Heroku deploy - An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

Tags: angular, heroku

My project runs perfectly on my local machine, but getting this error when trying to deploy live to Heroku:

I am getting the error: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

I have updated my Heroku engines to match my local machine as well:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "12.16.2",
  "npm": "6.14.4"
}
```

This is sitting in my dev dependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.1"
```

Here is the full Heroku log --tail errors:

```
admin-platform@0.0.0 start /app
ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.1" from devDependencies to dependencies in your package.json file! 
Had the same problem few minutes ago.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.1",
   ...
}
```

Be sure to change your start script to "node server.js" or the name of your server file, for further troubleshooting, here is a guide on how to deploy an angular app to heroku https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352